# Delete DOM elements by ID using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, dom

I'm trying to delete dynamically created DOM elements and for some reason I can't get it to work.

It's creating the objects fine and with the ID that I specified, but it won't delete.
The check on the `if` statement is working, because it prints out that `console.log()`.

Any ideas?

```
function displayLive()
{
  var previous = null;
  var current = null;
  setInterval(function()
              {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/showLive',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(response) 
      {
        current = JSON.stringify(response);
        if(previous !== current)
        {
          var obj = JSON.parse(response);
          console.log(obj);
          for(var i = 0; i < obj.active.length; i++)
          {
            if(obj.active[i].active === true)
            {
              $('.left').prepend($('<div/>', {class: 'profTemp', id: obj.active[i].userNameData}).append(
                $('<img/>', {src: obj.active[i].profiler, width: 40, height: 40}),
                $('<span/>', {text: " " + obj.active[i].userNameData}))); 

            }
            else if(obj.active[i].active === false)
            {
              $('#%s' , obj.active[i].userNameData).remove();
              console.log("getting in false");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }); 
    previous = current; 
  }, 2000);   
}
```

Comment: I think `%s` is a thing only inside `console` methods. I don't know if jQuery supports it. Try concatenating the id instead.

Comment: I tried that too and it didn't work

Comment: It could also be the userNameData has a '.' (dot) in there that causes problems with jquery and finding the item. $(document.getElementById(obj.active[i].userNameData)).remove() might help

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks guys!

Comment: No worries, I've bopped an answer in if you could just check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username has a dot in it (or other select character). Use

```
 $(document.getElementById(obj.active[i].userNameData)).remov‌​e()
```

To get around that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
$('#%s' , obj.active[i].userNameData).remove();
```

To :

```
$('#' + obj.active[i].userNameData).remove();
```

Comment: _why_ do you believe this is the answer? Please explain it, _why_ it works, _how_ it works?

Comment: Because i use javascript concatenation

For example :

`code`var id = obj.active[i].userNameData; // The string id = 'userName'
$('#' + id).remove();
it's same as:
$('#userName').remove();`code`

Comment: Include the explanation in your post, mate, not in the comments. Explain how the concatenation works, explain that the difference is the symbol.